# Scraping Issue: Only retrieving quotes from one page despite attempts to scrape multiple pages

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I was tasked with implementing a program that automatically scrapes all quotes (from all next pages) from the http://quotes.toscrape.com/js-delayed/ website and saves them to a single jsonl file upon execution.

To achieve this, I created the following script:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import jsonlines

class QuotesScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None
        self.wait = None
        self.load_env_vars()

    def load_env_vars(self):
        load_dotenv()
        self.proxy = os.getenv('PROXY')
        self.input_url = os.getenv('INPUT_URL')
        self.output_file = os.getenv('OUTPUT_FILE')

    def setup_driver(self):
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30)

    def scrape_page(self):
        time.sleep(20) 
        quote_elements = self.driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "quote")
        quotes = []
        for quote_element in quote_elements:
            text = quote_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "text").get_attribute("innerText")
            author = quote_element.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "author").get_attribute("innerText")
            tags = [tag.get_attribute("innerText") for tag in quote_element.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "tag")]
            quotes.append({"text": text, "by": author, "tags": tags})
        return quotes

    def scrape_quotes(self):
        self.driver.get(self.input_url)
        all_quotes = []
        while True:
            all_quotes.extend(self.scrape_page())
            try:
                next_page_button = self.wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "next")))
                next_page_button.click()
            except Exception:
                break
        return all_quotes

    def write_quotes_to_file(self, quotes):
        with jsonlines.open(self.output_file, mode='w') as writer:
            writer.write_all(quotes)

    def run(self):
        self.setup_driver()
        quotes = self.scrape_quotes()
        self.write_quotes_to_file(quotes)
        self.driver.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = QuotesScraper()
    scraper.run()
```

**The `output.jsonl` file is being saved correctly**, but it only does so for one page. I've tried different approaches to bypass this issue, but each time it only retrieves one page. My output.jsonl looks like this:

```
{"text": "“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”", "by": "Albert Einstein", "tags": ["change", "deep-thoughts", "thinking", "world"]}......
```

**How can I fix this? Is there a more optimal approach to this problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrote your code using `requests` and `bs4`, since the data already exists on the page in a `script` tag and takes 10 seconds to load on the page's HTML.

[image: Data Screenshot]

The code is as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import json
import os
import requests

class QuotesScraper:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = None
        self.wait = None
        self.load_env_vars()


    def load_env_vars(self):
        load_dotenv()
        self.input_url = os.getenv('INPUT_URL')
        self.input_host = os.getenv('INPUT_HOST')
        self.output_file = os.getenv('OUTPUT_FILE')


    def scrape_page(self, url): 
        print(url)
        
        return json.loads(bs(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml').find_all('script')[1].text.split('for (var i in data)')[0].split('var data =')[-1].strip().rstrip(';'))
        

    def scrape_quotes(self):
        url = self.input_url
        all_quotes = []
        while True:
            all_quotes.extend(self.scrape_page(url))

            next_page = bs(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml').find('li', {'class': 'next'})
            if not next_page:
                break
        
            else:
                url = self.input_host + next_page.find('a').get('href')

        return all_quotes

    def write_quotes_to_file(self, quotes):
        with open(self.output_file, mode='w') as f:
            json.dump(quotes, f)


    def run(self):
        quotes = self.scrape_quotes()
        self.write_quotes_to_file(quotes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scraper = QuotesScraper()
    scraper.run()
```

With `.env` having:

```
INPUT_HOST = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com'
INPUT_URL = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/js-delayed/'
OUTPUT_FILE = 'output.json'
```

And following is the sample output:

```
{
    "tags": [
        "change",
        "deep-thoughts",
        "thinking",
        "world"
    ],
    "author": {
        "name": "Albert Einstein",
        "goodreads_link": "/author/show/9810.Albert_Einstein",
        "slug": "Albert-Einstein"
    },
    "text": "“The world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It cannot be changed without changing our thinking.”"
},
{
    "tags": [
        "abilities",
        "choices"
    ],
    "author": {
        "name": "J.K. Rowling",
        "goodreads_link": "/author/show/1077326.J_K_Rowling",
        "slug": "J-K-Rowling"
    },
    "text": "“It is our choices, Harry, that show what we truly are, far more than our abilities.”"
}
```

This scraped all of the 10 pages and writes output in `JSON` format, instead of `JSONlines`, which is a more standardized way.

Comment: Thanks. I changed this line, but the result is still the same :(

Comment: Is it necessary that you need this in selenium?

Comment: I don't have to do it in Selenium. I didn't come up with any other solution. I'm open to other options. What can be used?

Comment: Thanks, works great! Do we need to use INPUT_HOST? In .env I should only have INPUT_URL and OUTPUT_FILE=output.jsonl

Comment: I used `INPUT_HOST` because the next page's anchor had absolute links, and I expected you needed abstraction since you hadn't mentioned the URL explicitly anywhere in the Python code. Using it or not using depends on your needs.